# How to fit regression lines per group ( each group contains two different factors/columns)?

Tags: r, plot, regression

I have managed to plot a generalized line, but it is not relevant to my needs. I want to plot line per each treatment and ID and to get the regression values. pic attached here:
[image]

I am relatively new with **R** and couldn't find a proper answer online. Thanks

This is my data:

[image]

I want to plot the regression lines for each combination of treatment (0/4/8)* and patient type.

the code that I have written is:

```
plot(ion_chlorophyll$NA,ion_chlorophyll$CHL)
plot(ion_chlorophyll$NA,ion_chlorophyll$CHL, pch = 1,cex = 1, col = "blue", main = "NA relationship", xlab ="Na", ylab ="CHL")
```

Comment: You should include the code that created the final data and the graph as well as the first 7-10 lines of the raw data so that people can help you get where you want to be.

Comment: Please help us help you by providing a reproducible example--that is, a sample of your data and the code you're running. For the data sample, paste into your question the output of `dput(data_sample)`. We probably need only about ten rows of data, but be sure to include data for at least two treatment IDs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and information. I Will edit the question

Comment: An image of your data is not helpful. We need something we can copy and paste into an R script. Please provide a sample of your data as described above. Also, `NA` is a missing data code in R, so you should use a different name for that column.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get multiple regression lines try using xyplot.
Experiment with the iris dataset.

```
library(lattice)

xyplot(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris, pch = 16, type = c("p", "g", "r"), groups = Species, auto.key = TRUE)
```

If you just have three factors contributing to your 2D plot, then it shouldn't be too much trouble to get the regression lines this way:

```
model1 <- lm(iris$Sepal.Length[iris$Species == "setosa"] ~ iris$Sepal.Width[iris$Species == "setosa"])

model2 <- lm(iris$Sepal.Length[iris$Species == "versicolor"] ~ iris$Sepal.Width[iris$Species == "versicolor"])

model3 <- lm(iris$Sepal.Length[iris$Species == "virginica"] ~ iris$Sepal.Width[iris$Species == "virginica"])
```

And do a `summary()` of each of the models to get the equations of the regression lines.

I think you should do something like this.

[image]

Comment: Does anyone know how I could make the legend solid points like in the graph? I tried fixing the legend, but I'm just not sure how to address it. I probably need to do something with auto.key, correct, but what?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `ggplot2` if you just want to plot. You can use `dplyr`, `tidy` and `broom` to get the predictions from the model. If `df` is your dataframe with columns - treatment, patient_type, Leaf_NA, Total_Chl,

**Just plot**

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- df %>% ggplot(aes(Leaf_NA, Total_Chl)) +
    facet_grid(treatment ~ patient_type) +
    stat_smooth(method='lm')
p
```

**Get model predictions**

```
library(dplyr) #for group_by(), inner_join(), mutate()
library(tidyr) #for nest(), unnest()
library(broom) #for augment()

model <- df %>%
    group_by(treatment, patient_type) %>%
    do(fit = lm(Total_Chl ~ Leaf_NA, data = .))

df %>%
    group_by(treatment, patient_type) %>%
    nest() %>%
    inner_join(model, .) %>%
    mutate(pred = list(augment(fit))) %>%
    unnest(pred)
```